# Fedora 23 and Nvidia 960M: a possible coexistence?

Tags: linux, graphics-card, fedora, nvidia-graphics-card

I have just installed Fedora 23 (with KDE) in a new Dell Inspiron 15-7559 but I could not figure out how to install any driver for my Nvidia GeForce GTX 960M (4GB GDDR5). At the moment, I am neither able to change the resolution (fixed to 4k) nor use the HDMI port.

I have tried several guides without any success, so I can accept any solution but I would prefer to use a free or open source solution. Anyway, my ultimate goal is to use an external (or, ideally, two) monitor(s).

Nvidia 960M implements the Optimus technology so I followed the instructions found in this page https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Bumblebee#For_free_or_open_source_solution_fedora .

## Free or Open Source solution

If I give the 2 following commands:

```
 dnf -y --nogpgcheck install http://install.linux.ncsu.edu/pub/yum/itecs/public/bumblebee/fedora23/noarch/bumblebee-release-1.2-1.noarch.rpm
 dnf install bumblebee-nouveau
```

then I can reboot but I will receive the following error:

```
 [root@localhost mirko]# optirun -vv glxinfo
 [  391.739812] [DEBUG]Reading file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf
 [  391.740185] [INFO]Configured driver: nouveau                  
 [  391.740653] [DEBUG]optirun version 3.2.1 starting...   
 [  391.740701] [DEBUG]Active configuration:                
 [  391.740717] [DEBUG] bumblebeed config file: /etc/bumblebee/bumblebee.conf        
 [  391.740733] [DEBUG] X display: :8                                                          
 [  391.740749] [DEBUG] LD_LIBRARY_PATH:                                             
 [  391.740767] [DEBUG] Socket path: /var/run/bumblebee.socket                                               
 [  391.740783] [DEBUG] Accel/display bridge: auto                                                     
 [  391.740798] [DEBUG] VGL Compression: proxy    
 [  391.740814] [DEBUG] VGLrun extra options: 
 [  391.740829] [DEBUG] Primus LD Path: /usr/lib/primus:/usr/lib64/primus              
 [  391.740974] [DEBUG]Using auto-detected bridge virtualgl                                                                 
 [  391.893669] [INFO]Response: No - error: [XORG] (EE) Failed to load module "mouse" (module does not exist, 0)        
 [  391.893696] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) Failed to load module "mouse" (module does not exist, 0)                                            
 [  391.893703] [DEBUG]Socket closed.                                                                  
 [  391.893720] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.                                                        
 [  391.893726] [DEBUG]Killing all remaining processes.
```

If it throw the following command then, after the reboot, I will get just a blank screen.

```
 dnf install bumblebee-nouveau bbswitch-dkms kernel-devel
```

## Closed source solution

I would prefer to use a free or open source solution, if it is possible to connect external monitors without problem, but maybe this log can be helpful.
Installing the managed NVidia repo and the No multilib fedora 22+, if I reboot I will get the some blank screen without any accessible shell.
These are the output of bumblebee-nvidia --check and --debug

```
 [root@localhost mirko]# bumblebee-nvidia --check
 --force compile selected via /etc/sysconfig/nvidia/compile-nvidia-driver
 Warning! This NVIDIA driver has not compiled successfully before on kernel 4.3.3-300.fc23.x86_64!
 Warning! This NVIDIA driver userland
 /usr/lib64/nvidia-bumblebee/libGL.so.1 library is missing!
 Warning! nvidia.ko was not created in in the kernel tree!
 modinfo output for NVIDIA:
 modinfo: ERROR: Module nvidia not found.
 Check bbswitch kernel module...
 Warning! bbswitch is not loaded into this kernel!
 Since bbswitch is not loaded into the kernel, lets do additional checks on it...
 dkms status bbswitch output:
 bbswitch, 0.8.0, 4.3.3-300.fc23.x86_64, x86_64: installed
 if the bbswitch package is installed, you may wish to try:
 /usr/sbin/dkms add -m bbswitch -v 0.8.0
 /usr/sbin/dkms build -m bbswitch -v 0.8.0
 /usr/sbin/dkms install -m bbswitch -v 0.8.0
 /sbin/modprobe bbswitch
 To get clues as to why bbswitch is failing on this kernel...
 All NVIDIA checks completed, but there were 1 or more failures...
 Try running this script with the --debug option to find clues about what has
 gone wrong with the NVIDIA driver compile process.
 
 [root@localhost mirko]# bumblebee-nvidia --debug
 --force compile selected via /etc/sysconfig/nvidia/compile-nvidia-driver
 --debug mode selected.
 Building NVIDIA video drivers: Creating directory NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-352.63
 Verifying archive integrity... OK
 Uncompressing NVIDIA Accelerated Graphics Driver for Linux-x86_64 352.63...........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................
                           [  OK  ]
 sed: can't read /usr/share/applications/nvidia-settings.desktop: No such file or directory
```

I hope that you can help me because I love Linux and I would really like to use just it in my life. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I add that I am using Fedora 64bit and xorg-x11-drv-vmmouse.x86_64 (Xorg vmmouse input driver) is already installed.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using the RPM fusion?  Unlike bumblebee, I have found that using RPM Fusion all the needed NVIDIA drivers are properly installed. More information as well as a detailed tutorial on how to install NVIDIA drivers can be found [here](https://rpmfusion.org/Howto/nVidia#Optimus).

Comment: Adding the process for using RPM Fusion to install/update nVidia drivers would make this a much better answer. Links can change and expire, and so leaving all the important information at the end of a link makes this a much less valuable answer.